Is it feasible to use a mini-PC with a 4G USB stick as an internet router?
So, I've bought a TP Linux 5G router/access point, the X50-5G. For my purposes, it's garbage, despite the good reviews online.
It asked to be updated, I did that, once I did it, every time it gets reset, the Wifi network stops working and I have to re-do the entire setup from their Android app.
I have a slightly older Lenovo mini-PC (probably about 3 years old), ThinkCentre M75N IoT.
I was thinking of attaching an USB 4G (LTE) SIM card reader, something like this.
Now, I'd want to put a Linux distro on it and run it 24/7 as the internet router for a household with not that much heavy duty internet usage (think 10GB data usage per month, in total).
Can anyone recommend some guides for this? Even for the 4G LTE SIM card reader, brands/models?
Is it a good idea? I already have the PC lying around doing nothing.

I'd try opensense or some other router distro. You can build one off a regular linux distro - but I believe both the guides I know of -  ars technica's one https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/04/the-ars-guide-to-building-a-linux-router-from-scratch/ and mine are a little outdated.

How is Linux hardware support for those 4G USB sticks?

Is there a reason you feel it is not going to be a good fit? Questions asking that we find guides for you aren't on topic on this site. I recommend that you do some research and begin working toward a solution, and as you come upon specific problems you are facing while doing that, present those here and we should be pretty able to help you with those. But as this question currently is, it will be closed for being off topic.

In my limited experience, a minimal install of opensense mainly uses the storage for configuration. I think the minimum is about 4GB for the install target. I think it is free-bsd if you want to dig into compatability. In any event it is open source and free to try.

The miniPC is more than capable of the role you intend. The modem, OTOH, isn't the best option for what you want. If the miniPC has the optional Intel® 9260 802.11AC that is several steps above the integrated AP the ZTE dongle (and this one isn't manageable from the OS, it's its own AP, managed, at best, from the modem's web interface only).  I suggest a simpler 4G/5G USB modem that emulates Ethernet  for better compatibility and an additional USB WiFi device if you don't have the optional internal.

In addition to @JourneymanGeek’s suggestion, something like openWRT is a Linux distro that would already be quite setup for routing, and is pretty easy to use.

@music2myear - I want to use a PC with a 4G/LTE stick. Can it be done easily? How is hardware support for 4G sticks? That's the core question. I want the internet to come through the mobile data connection, and I want it shared in the household through Wifi.

@Yorik: 4G SIM USB sticks, not 4GB. 4G as in GSM/LTE/... The inbound connection would be through the mobile data network.

@ChanganAuto: Aren't the ones which emulate Ethernet also the ones which have their own web UI, because Ethernet emulation means they can't be configured in the normal "direct" way? (Often those USB sticks can do both modes though, depending on which USB configuration the OS selects...)

@grawity_u1686 Indeed. That wasn't the main point though. The OP's link is for a "mini-router" (modem+AP). Its AP is not managed from the OS which is desirable in this setup. The WiFi in the miniPC is optional so I alerted to the fact that's not a good idea to use a MiFi of sorts for WiFi. The modem should e modem only (emulating Ethernet is a plus) and the WiFi should be internal or USB managed by the miniPC's OS.
